# Consultas en catalogo de sistema de PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Hola soy nueva en esto de hacer consultas en el catalogo de sistema de postgresql y no acabo de entender muy bien como funciona.

Me han pedido un ejercicio en el que tengo que listar el nombre y el atributo de la clave alternativa de aquellas tablas de la base de datos activa que tenga una clave alternativa (suponiendo que es simple).

Me han dicho que use esta página web [Catalogo sistema postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/catalogs.html) ,pero por mucho que lo leo no se por donde cogerlo ni como funcionan este tipo de consultas (selects). He estado mirando [pg_attribute](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/catalog-pg-attribute.html) y veo que tiene como unos "atributos" que se pueden usar en la consulta pero tampoco especifica como usarlo o que se puede hacer con ellos, o almenos yo no tengo ni idea.
He pensado que se podrían usar attname para el nombre y attalign para la clave alternativa

Alguien me puede ayudar porfavor?

He pensado algo tipo esto:

```
select attname, attalign from pg_attribute where attalign = true;
```

Pero me da error y no se muy bien construirlo.

El error es el siguiente:

```
ERROR:  el operador no existe: "char" = boolean
LÍNEA 1: ...t attname, attalign from pg_attribute where attalign = true;
                                                                 ^
SUGERENCIA:  Ningún operador coincide en el nombre y tipos de argumentos. Puede ser necesario agregar conversión explícita de tipos.
```

A continuación he probado a colocar:

```
 select attname, attalign from pg_attribute where attalign ='true';


attname | attalign
---------+----------
(0 filas)
```

y saca la tabla sin resultado, no se si estoy haciendo mal o es asi?

Comment: Checa [ask] tu pregunta es confusa y por lo tanto difícil de responder

Comment: no se como preguntarla de otra forma, he sido lo mas especifica posible, voy a tratar de modificarla un poco para que sea mas entendible pero no se como hacerlo.

Comment: podrias pasar a leer https://www.dataprix.com/es/bases-datos-master-software-libre-uoc/24-clave-candidata-clave-primaria-y-clave-alternativa, es un buen articulo.

Comment: Muchas gracias! pero yo necesito hacer una consulta al catalogo de sistema de la base datos  de postgresql, es decir extraer los datos de las claves alternativas, los nombres de usuario, etc que hay internamente de postgresql

Comment: Qué error da la consulta?

Comment: Edito la pregunta con el error :)

Comment: Esa columna es proyección de pgtype y sólo tiene valores c,s,i,d (sí, es un char, por eso el error) para decir si es char, string, int, double. De hecho, la misma documentación que citas indica que el campo es un char, poco lograrás comparando con un string o con bool

Comment: Como podría realizar el ejercicio que me piden ? Es correcto lo que yo propongo?

Comment: Yo buscaría como claves alternativas, las claves candidatas que no sean la PK. Eso es, los campos NOT NULL y con alta selectividad (con constraint UNIQUE, por ejemplo).

Answer (score 0):

Para buscar claves alternativas, habría que identificar las claves candidatas que no sean la PK

Lo primero es encontrar las que son NOT NULL

`select attname from pg_attribute where attnotnull = true;`

También haría falta revisar en pg_index para comprobar qué columnas hacen parte de las PK. En pg_index están los índices, pero la relación con las columnas se da a través del

```
select 
attname
from pg_index idx 
LEFT JOIN ON idx.indkey = att.attnum
WHERE indisunique = true
```

Y así. Ir creando el conjunto de las que se podrían considerar claves alternativas.

Habría que filtrar además, las columnas que sólo sean de tablas en un esquema *de usuario*, porque si no se hace, te mostrará las columnas de las tablas del catálogo (sí, es autorreferente). En la tabla pg_class están todas las tablas (y todo lo que parece tabla, como las vistas y los índices), indicando quién es el usuario dueño de ellas.

```
select relowner
from pg_class 
where relkind = 'r';
```

No hay una forma sencilla de explorar el catálogo. Puedes revisar la documentación para familiarizarte más con él antes de resolver el problema, que no se resuelve con una sola consulta (a menos que el criterio para claves candidatas sea *laxo* )

Comment: ajam vale, el problema que tengo es que yo todo esto no lo termino de entender, no se muy bien como funciona y tampoco veo que en ningún lado diga pues esto va un poco así, digamos que acabo de empezar a tocar todo esto y la verdad que lo veo una muralla enorme que no entiendo, he estado revisando pg_attribute buscando attnotnull pero no lo encuentro, como funcionan las consultas del catalogo de sistema? que es lo que deberia fijarme y donde puedo encontrar documentacion o algun lugar donde me explique esto como va? Este sería el resultado correcto para la pregunta? podrías explicarme un poco?

Comment: Explicar todo el catálogo escapa un poco al alcance de la pregunta -de la respuesta.. y de StackOverflow-. Resumen: La BD guarda metadatos de cómo son las tablas y es ese catálogo que refieres, el que muestra qué tablas usa PGSQL para eso. En una tiene cómo son las columnas de las tablas, otra para índices, otra para usuarios y roles, etc. Yo muestro parte de lo que podrías hacer para decir "estas son las claves alternativas" pero falta y la respuesta no pretende explicar en detalle cómo funciona el catálogo. Espero te sirva